# Memory leak in TPacker.SplitNode

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks

I found a simple binary packer unit online which I altered to fit my needs. It works nicely but I am leaking memory.

`TSprite`

```
type
  TSprite=class
  public
    X:Integer;
    Y:Integer;
    Width:Integer;
    Height:Integer;
    Used:Boolean;
    Down:TSprite;
    Right:TSprite;
    constructor Create(X, Y,Width, Height:Integer);
end;
```

`TPacker`

```
type
  TPacker=class
  public
  Root:TSprite;
  constructor Create(W,H:Integer; Image : TImage);
  destructor Destroy; override;
  function Fit(var Blocks:array of TBlock):Boolean;
  function FindNode(root:TSprite; W, H:Integer):TSprite;
  function SplitNode(Node:Tsprite; W, H:Integer):TSprite;
end;
```

I use it like this

```
var Packer:TPacker;

  Packer:=TPacker.Create(Width  , Height, Image);

  Packer.Fit(Blocks);

  Boundary(Packer.Root, Image);

  for I := Low(Blocks) to High(Blocks) do
    begin
      if Blocks[I].Fit <> nil then
        Draw(Blocks[I].Fit.X,Blocks[I].Fit.Y,Blocks[I].Width,Blocks[I].Height, Image);
    end;



  LeftRacks:=Report(blocks, packer.Root.Width, packer.Root.Height).Racks;
  FillPercent:=Report(blocks, packer.Root.Width, packer.Root.Height).FillPercent;

  Packer.Free;
```

Constructor for the `TPacker`

```
constructor TPacker.Create(W: Integer; H: Integer; Image : TImage);
var temp : integer;
begin
  // 100x100 is our smalles unit . So to create a nice Packview we always
  // change W,H to neerest value which is dividable by 100.
  temp:=0;
  temp:=W mod 100;
  W:=W-temp;

  temp:=0;
  temp:= H mod 100;
  H:=H-temp;

  Image.Width:=W+1;
  Image.Height:=H+1;

  Self.Root := TSprite.Create(0,0,W,H);
  Self.Root.Used:=false;
  Self.Root.Down:=nil;
  Self.Root.Right:=nil;
end;
```

Here was the first memory leak , which I fixed in the destructor

```
destructor TPacker.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(Root);

  inherited;
end;
```

The current leak occurs in the `SplitNode` because it creates new nodes in which I lose track and I don't know how to free them properly.

```
function TPacker.SplitNode(Node: TSprite; W: Integer; H: Integer):TSprite;
begin
  Node.Used := true;
    Node.Down := TSprite.Create(Node.X , Node.Y + H , Node.Width , Node.Height - H);
    Node.Right := TSprite.Create(Node.X + W , Node.Y , Node.Width - W , H);
  Result := Node;
end;
```

`SplitNode` is used in this `Fit` function

```
function TPacker.Fit(var Blocks: array of TBlock):Boolean;
var
  I:Integer;
  Node:TSprite;
  temp:integer;
begin
   for I := Low(Blocks) to High(Blocks) do
    begin
      Node:=Self.FindNode(Self.Root, Blocks[I].Width, Blocks[I].Height);
      // we rotate it and try again just in case...
      if Assigned(Node) = false then
        begin
          temp:=Blocks[I].Width;
          Blocks[I].Width:=Blocks[I].Height;
          Blocks[I].Height:=temp;

          Node:=Self.FindNode(Self.Root, Blocks[I].Width, Blocks[I].Height);
        end;

      if Assigned(Node) then
        begin
          Blocks[I].Fit := Self.SplitNode(node, Blocks[I].Width, Blocks[I].Height);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: What if the destructor of `TSprite` will do a `Down.Free; Right.Free;`?

Comment: OK I did it , but I must confess I have no idea why it works now ?

when I FreeAndNil(Root) without the Destructor for the TSprite it only kills the first one?
but if I add the Down.Free and Right.Free to the TSPrite Destructor then it somehow automagically traverses all
sprites till none are left?

destructor TSprite.Destroy;
begin
  Down.Free;
  Right.Free;

  inherited;
end;

Comment: Thank you very much! I would like to mark your comment as the answer , but it seems it is not allowed....

Comment: Posted as answer instead.

Comment: If you just FreeAndNil (why not just Free? -- it can never be accessed anymore) the Root, the doesn't cause a recursive call to delete all split nodes. Explanation in the excellent answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You explicitly create and destroy the `TSprite` used as `Root` in the `TPacker` class. But `SplitNode` creates many more `TSprite` objects implicitly in a tree structure. There is no automatism that will clean up these additional objects. These `TSprite`s are referenced, though (`Down` and `Right`), so each `TSprite` has references to the additional `TSprite`s it was split into and can clean them up. If each one does that clean up, the whole tree will be destroyed recursively.

So the solution is to write a destructor for `TSprite`:

```
destructor TSprite.Destroy;
begin
  Down.Free;
  Right.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```